# Does Cast<T> cause an IQueryable to evaluate in Linq-to-SQL? What are the restrictions on its use?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, casting, expression, iqueryable

Does Cast cause an IQueryable to evaluate in Linq-to-SQL?

What are the restrictions on its use?

It seems like if I created an explicit conversion for a record to a domain object like:

```
  IQueryable<TSqlRecord> q;
  var cast = q.Cast<TDomainObject>();
```

Then I should get an error, because Linq-to-Sql and obviously can't process the domain object constructor.

But, can I cast `IQueryable<TSqlRecord>` to its interface `IHasIntId` without forcing the query to evaluate?

Comment: I think Linq to Sql need to have the correct ElementType to be able to build the Sql, the LinqProvider probably use DataContext.GetTable(Type) (not sure so I didn't made an answer...). But you can write generic extension methods with type contraints on  an interface (static IQueryable<T> Bla<T>() where T : IHasIntId) to factorize code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast is deferred and does not cause immediate execution.  This is because it does not (itself) enumerate the source.  Only when something is enumerated, is the query run.

Upcasting is no problem.  The query will work fine.

Recall - the query works on database rows and not on instances.  Instances are only created when the rows arrive locally.  All that this call to cast does is to change the reference type used in the result - it doesn't change the type of instance new'd up.

```
class SpecificObject : DomainObject

MyDataContext myDC = new MyDataContext();
IQueryable<DomainObject> query = myDC.SpecificObjects.Cast<DomainObject>();

Console.WriteLine(myDC.GetCommand(query).CommandText);
```

But - that's not really useful - as the properties on the row were on the original type and now you can't refer to those properties in the rest of the query.

---

Downcasting doesn't really do much.  LinqToSql presumes that the each row is of type T from the `Table<T>`.  Not some TChild.  This will generate a query selecting null for each row from the table.

```
class SpecificObject : DomainObject

MyDataContext myDC = new MyDataContext();
IQueryable<SpecificObject> query = myDC.DomainObjects.Cast<SpecificObject>();

Console.WriteLine(myDC.GetCommand(query).CommandText);
```

---

Implicit conversion... one should be very careful with that.  Even LinqToObject's `Enumerable.Cast<T>` doesn't respect implicit conversion operations (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2008/02/16/breaking-change-in-linq-queries-using-explicitly-typed-range-variables.aspx) and [here](http://www.kenegozi.com/blog/2009/10/01/linq-cast-extension-method-and-invalidcastexception)).  Of course, that doesn't have anything to do with LinqToSql - but the principle matters - .net casting is not the same as c# implicit conversion and whatever sql thing.  You must bear in mind the execution environment of the code you're writing.

Comment: Great answer - Just to clarify, What I'm trying to do is inject an IQueryable<ISimpleModel> into a service whose assembly does not reference the assembly with my DataContext.  ISimpleModel is implemented in a partial of the the autogenerated SimpleModel class.  From your answer I have gathered that calling Cast<ISimpleModel>() to the Table<SimpleModel> will be sufficient.  Correct?

Comment: That should be sufficient.  I wouldn't do that (passing query instances between projects runs the risk that coders lose track of the rules for where the query eventually runs)... but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't cast `IQueryable<TSqlRecord>` to `IHasIntId`, because `IQueryable<TSqlRecord>` represents multiple objects of type `TSqlRecord`, whereas `IHasIntId` only represents one object. At least, that's how I understand your sample.
I think, your question should have been asked like this:

> Can I cast `IQueryable<TSqlRecord>` to `IQueryable<IHasIntId>`.

The answer to that question is: **No, it's not possible**
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb301460%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) states the following:

> The Cast(IQueryable) method generates a MethodCallExpression that represents calling Cast(IQueryable) itself as a constructed generic method. It then passes the MethodCallExpression to the CreateQuery(Expression) method of the IQueryProvider represented by the Provider property of the source parameter.
>
> The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression tree that represents calling Cast(IQueryable) depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The expected behavior is that it converts the values in source to type TResult.

This means, that the call to `Cast` is not really executed, but interpreted by the query provider and for example translated into SQL.